# Can i connect my solar system to the ground wire of a grid outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding, ground

I have solar panels on the roof (ungrounded) and an ATS to switch between solar (ungrounded) and grid power. (grounded)

EDIT : Sorry, my question wasn't clear enough, I'm talking about AC. My questions are :

1-  can i connect cable number 1 and 2 ? (1 is connected to a ground rod and 2 is the ground wire running in the house)

2 - Can i put copper wires around my solar panels / inverter box and ground them by connecting them to the grid power ground wire too ? (wire number 1)

NEW EDIT : I should add too that I have some appliances connected directly to the grid power too. (And its ground wire 1.) Can they interfere or something ? Aka green wires here are just a cord connected to an outlet from the grid.

[image]

Comment: Usually grid power is AC, and solar cells are always DC.  I would expect that whatever sort of inverter you're using would deal with the grounding issues.

Comment: The metal casing of my inverter isn't connected to ground yet. How is my inverter supposed to deal with grounding issues ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "ground." Your question is kind of vague and because of that you are likely to get answers that are not right. I very strongly suggest that you simply hire an electrician or spend some time studying the electrical code applicable where you live. Grounding is surprisingly complicated.

Comment: I live in France 220v, what i call no ground is : just 2 wires connected instead of the 3 from the "wire pack". (Yellow not connected to anything)

Comment: In the US many especially newer mounting systems for solar panels (rack systems) are designed and approved to electrically bond the panel frames and rack together electrically. But you still need to electrically bond your rack system to the grid green wire ground. You may also need to drive a ground rod depending on local code and inspector bias/point of view. As far as "grounding" the negative or positive wires for your PV string, you need to check the inverter instructions. I believe negative ground is most common but not universal. Like I said it is complicated.

Comment: @mkeith So... if i connect my solar ground wire to the ground wire of the grid (that is connected to a ground rod), ... something dangerous can happen ?

Comment: I still think it is unclear what you want to connect to mains earth/ground. Are you talking about the panel DC return wire, i.e  the negative supply wire?

Comment: What are you using for an inverter in this setup? What do you have for ground-fault protection on the DC side?

Comment: It is not only a matter of what you connect but how. If you don't use the right fittings you may run into a serious corrosion problem trying to connect copper wire to an aluminum solar module frame. But in general, yes, the metal frames of the solar modules must somehow be kept at earth potential for touch safety. So it is not bad to ground it per se. But if the rack system is designed to provide an electrical ground, then it may not be necessary to ground the modules. Just ground the rack. How you do that will depend on the electrical code in your country which I am not familar with.

Comment: Since you are grid tied you will be required to have the system bonded this should be specified by the utility they usually have different requirements than the NEC but article 690.45 thru 47 of the electrical code calls for #6 copper 4 aluminum

Comment: @EdBeal OP mentioned that they are in France.

Comment: Sorry everyone, i added a picture to represent it better.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have no grounding at all for now. DC or AC.

Comment: when you say you have "no grounding" do you mean you have no earthing connections to receptacles, or do you mean you have no earthing electrode?  Do you have a RCD in your distribution board?

Comment: I have everything on my grid system. (green wires on the image) The new system has nothing yet. (wires purple and black on the image)

Comment: @bobdylan -- what open-circuit voltage does your solar system run at?

Comment: 24v battery with 230v ac inverter.

Comment: @bobdylan -- I'm asking for the open-circuit-voltage of your solar panel array :) (i.e. the maximum voltage they can supply to your charge controller/MPPT's input)

Comment: I think about 36 volt.

Comment: @bobdylan at this point, I think your best bet would be to touch base with A) the PV cell manufacturer/retailer, B) the local power company, or C) the local building/electrical inspector who will (presumably) be checking your installation when you're finished. I don't think anyone here is going to be able to chime in with a really good answer for you. On the bright side, you've managed to stump a pretty knowledgeable group, so you've got that going for you! :)